# Why does my RPI4 not work with a female-to-female HDMI adaptor and HDMI extension cable?

Tags: hdmi, video, cable, connectors

My RPi4 works fine with a micro-HDMI to HDMI cable. But because that cable is too short I have bought a female-to-female HDMI adaptor (coupler) that I use to extend the micro-HDMI to HDMI cable with another regular (HDMI to HDMI) cable.

This extension works fine when I connect a RPI3 or my laptop to a computer monitor or to the TV (using it to connect two regular HDMI-to-HDMI cables). However, with the RPi4 and the micro-HDMI to HDMI cable it doesn't; both the monitor and TV display the "no signal" message.

I don't think the F/F HDMI adaptor is faulty, because it works fine with anything but the RPi4.

What could cause this?

// F

Comment: Which OS are you using? Maybe the additional connections are not allowing the HDMI EDID resolution information through? Why not just buy a longer micro hdmi to hdmi cable?

Comment: I'm currently using LibreElec but the issue also exists using RaspbarryOS (latest versions of both). If the additional connector doesn't pass HDME IDID resolution data it shouldn't work with my laptop, either, I would imagine. Yes, I can buy a longer cable but I'm trying to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: It would have been wiser here to just get a longer micro cable, or a micro HDMI adapter you can use at the end of a normal cable.  Right now you have two different cables with a do-hickey in the middle.  I suspect the signal from the Pi is too weak -- which might also be because of the length.  How long is it?

Comment: The original micro-HDMi to HDMI cable is 75cm, the HDMI-to-HDMI cable I'm attaching to it is 1 metre.